# How to asynchronously call functions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have some list of functions to call in controller say

```
$scope.trader = {};

$scope.getUserLocation();
$scope.searchPaymentMethod($scope.trader.cityname);
$scope.getUserCurrency();
```

and each of these functions make an HTTP call to get some data. Say `getUserLocation` does this...

```
$scope.getUserLocation = function() {
    var dataPromise = locationServiceCustomised.getCurrentLocation();
    dataPromise.then(function(result) {
        $scope.trader.cityname=result.countryName;
    });
}
```

and these all functions set some value to `$scope.trader` whose value is being used in calling another function.

Now how to make one by one Asynchronous call to each of these functions so that these functions work one after another.

My full code is somewhat like this...

```
$scope.trader = {};

$scope.getOfferList = function() {

    if($scope.trader.cityname == null || $scope.trader.cityname == '') {
            $scope.getUserLocation();
        }

    $scope.searchPaymentMethod($scope.trader.cityname);
    $scope.getUserCurrency();
}

$scope.getUserLocation = function() {
    var dataPromise = locationServiceCustomised.getCurrentLocation();
    dataPromise.then(function(result) {
        $scope.trader.cityname=result.countryName;
    });
}

$scope.searchPaymentMethod = function(country) {
    locationService.paymentMethod({cityname: country}, function(data) {
        ------- Some Functionality-------
    });
};

$scope.getOfferList();
```

Comment: Use callback as parameter or return promise for each function call and use `.then` method chaining.

Comment: define `work one after another`... is each dependent on data from the the previous one?

Comment: I can't use callback as $scope.getUserLocation is not returning any value. Its just setting value of $scope.trader.cityname

Any other suggestion ?

Comment: I have re edited my code please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have asynchronous functions that depend on values obtained from previous asynchronous functions, you need to chain promises with `.then`. If the functions can be called in parallel, then you need to use `$q.all`.

In your case, `searchPaymentMethod` is strictly dependent on value from `getLocation`, while `getUserCurrency` can be done in parallel.

```
$scope.getOfferList = function() {

   var paymentMethodPromise = 
     $q.when($scope.trader.cityname)
       .then(function(cachedLocation){
          if (cachedLocation) return cachedLocation;

          return getUserLocation();
       })
       .then(function(location){
          // cache, if needed, but better do this in a service
          $scope.trader.cityname = location;
          return searchPaymentMethod(location);
       });

   var currencyPromise = getUserCurrency();

   // when all complete, calculate offerList
   return $q.all({ 
                  paymentMethod: paymentMethodPromise,
                  currency: currencyPromise })
            .then(function(data){
               var paymentMethod = data.paymentMethod,
                   currency = data.currency;

               // based on that get offerList
               return offersList;
            })

};
```

Needless to say, that for this to work, the expectation is for all these functions (i.e. `searchPaymentMethod`, `getUserLocation`, etc...) return a promise of the right value. As an example, `getUserLocation` doesn't do that now, and should be changed to something like the following:

```
function getUserLocation(){
   return locationServiceCustomised
           .getCurrentLocation()
           .then(function(location){
             // manipulate the result if needed
             return location.cityName;
           })
}
```

A few other things to note:

1. You don't need to expose every function on the `$scope` - expose only the ones that need to be invoked from the View, e.g. `<button ng-click="getOfferList()">`
2. It's better to leave the cached-or-not decision to the service (that should implement these functions) and leave a clean API for the controller.

Comment: Hey... in my case searchPaymentMethod() is dependent on $scope.trader.cityname. If it doesn't exists only then to call $scope.getUserLocation() and later searchPaymentMethod(). But if $scope.trader.cityname already exists then directly call searchPaymentMethod().

Comment: Yes, and that is what happens with `if (cachedLocation) return cachedLocation;` `cachedLocation` come `.when` above it

Comment: Ok I am checking this

Comment: 1 more thing I need to ask.. 

In function getUserLocation(), if locationServiceCustomised.getCurrentLocation() is returning some JSON and I need to return a specific value then ho to do that.

What I have tried is this
function getUserLocation(){
 locationServiceCustomised.getCurrentLocation().then(function(result) {
 return result.cityName;
})
}

in this case, its returning undefined in second

.then(function(location){......

Comment: @KamaldeepSingh,  Yes, add `.then(function(result){...}`, but you no longer need any `deferred.resolve`s... just return whatever the value you need from that `.then`

Comment: @KamaldeepSingh, what is `undefined`? the `location`? are you actually doing `return locationServiceCustomized.getCurrentLocation...`? - don't forget the `return`

Comment: No I am using it like this-----   

function getUserLocation(){ locationServiceCustomised.getCurrentLocation().then(function(result) {

console.log("Test "+JSON.stringify(result));
return result.cityName;

})
}


And the Test log returns this "countryLanguage":"en","cityName":"Japan" 

SO I want to return only result.cityName and finally set $scope.trader.cityname in second .then(function(location){......

Comment: @KamaldeepSingh, read my previous comment carefully again, but I'll repeat here - don't forget the `return`, i.e. do `return locationServiceCustomized.getCurrentLocation`

Comment: Can you please give an example... Sorry I am not getting you

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to chain promises. So, first of all, all your functions have to return a promise. So, for your first function you would have:

```
$scope.getUserLocation = function() {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   locationServiceCustomised.getCurrentLocation.then(function(result) {
       deferred.resolve(result);
    });
   return deferred;
}
```

Then just chain it:

```
$scope.getUserLocation()
    .then($scope.searchPaymentMethod)        
    .then($scope.getUserCurrency);
```

where

```
$scope.searchPaymentMethod = function(input) {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   $scope.trader.cityname = input.cityname;
   // do some computationn
   deferred.resolve(whateveryouwanttoreturn);
   returnn deferred;
}
```

Comment: Any other solution....
Look... there could be chance that I already have the value of $scope.trader.cityname so in that case I need not to call $scope.getUserLocation(). I will directly call $scope.searchPaymentMethod()


I am re editing my code please check

Comment: But one more case is there that I have to call $scope.getUserLocation() function only when $scope.trader.cityname = null;